# How to install shapely on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, shapely

I have tried to install shapely on Ubuntu 12.10. Therefore I installed libgeos-c1, pip and shapely with `$ pip install Shapely`. The shapely files are now in /home/user/build/Shapely. When I try to import it in my python script with

`from shapely.geometry import Point`

gives the following error:

`from shapely.geometry import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named shapely.geometry`

Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For easier installation the module is in the repositories:

`sudo apt-get install python-shapely`

From the directory you said, you've installed the module in a non standard place and not in a  path that is being watched by python.

To check which paths are currently active you can issue the following from within the python interpreter:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Of course you can always append your custom path with

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_library')
#And then
import shapely
```